# Laravel forms with models

Tags: php, laravel, forms, contacts

I have this code for my form and it works well:

```
    <div class="form-group">

        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
        <option>Assign</option>
        @foreach ($projects as $project)
        <option>{{ $project->name }} </option>

        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

but what I'm trying to do is this with a contact form:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('name', 'Project') !!}
            {!! Form::select (@theforeach with the values :c ) !!}}
        </div>
```

I'm using the use `App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;` and I have been searching the way of doing it but there is to few examples on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your select options to works, you need to call it properly,

From controller,

```
 // Example : This is for single view page

 $list_of_options = Products::pluck('name','id');
 return view('your_view_name',compact('list_of_options')); 

// Example : If you want select dropdown in all page ( within the controller views)   then,

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function __construct(){
   View::share('list_of_options',Products::pluck('name','id'));  
}
```

Now in blade,

```
  {{ dd($list_of_options); }} // Check if the values are comming in proper formate

  {!! Form::select('name_of_the_select', $list_of_options, null ,[
         'class' => 'form-control',
         'id'    => 'name_of_the_select'
      ]);
   !!}
```

Here is the button with `<i>` or `<span>` inside of it :-

```
{{ Form::button(
    '<span class="fa fa-play fa-1x"></span>',
        [
            'class'=>'btn btn-info',
            'type'=>'button'
        ])
    }}
```

From your question ( **UPDATED** )

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('exampleSelect1', 'Project') !!}
{!! Form::select('projects', $projects, null ,[
             'class'       => 'form-control',
             'id'          => 'exampleSelect1',
             'placeholder' => 'Please select project'

          ]);
       !!}
    </div>
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: thanks for the code, you are very helpfull, in your example you put

(your blade code)

and in my html i have a <i class="fas fa-play fa-1x"></i> inside the button, how can i add to that expression? 

Thanks again dude

Comment: Can you please update your blade code in your question which you're trying to do and hey that's okay i'm here to help :)

Comment: I updated my answer please let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks ViperTecPro, how can update my code on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

[Form](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) is part of the Laravel Collective HTML library, you can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.6/html.md), specifically you're looking for the [Select](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.6/html.md#drop-down-lists) documentation:

```php
echo Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small']);
```

You have a Collection of `Project` models, each with a `name` and (presumably) an `id` which you need to turn into a key -> value array for the `select` method which you can do using [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck):

```php
{!! Form::select('project', $projects->pluck('name', 'id')) !!}
```

Then within your controller you'll be able to find the project that has been selected using `find`, e.g:

```php
Project::find($request->project);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('project', 'Project') !!}
    {!! Form::select ('project', $projects->pluck('name')) !!}} 
</div>
```

See docs https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('project', 'Project') !!}
    {!! Form::select ('project', $projects->pluck('name', 'id')) !!}}
</div>
```